# How to prove the distribution of Generalised Instrumental Variables Estimator

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variables, mathematical-statistics

$\hat { \beta } _ { GI V } = ( X ^ { \prime } Z ( Z ^ { \prime } Z ) ^ { - 1 } Z ^ { \prime } X ) ^ { - 1 } X ^ { \prime } Z ( Z ^ { \prime } Z ) ^ { - 1 } Z^ { \prime }y\hspace{35pt}(a)$

$(a)$ is the definition of the generalised instrumental variables estimator.

I know the distribution is

$\sqrt { N } ( \hat { \beta } _ { I V } - \beta ) \rightarrow N ( 0 , \sigma ^ { 2 } ( \Sigma _ { x z } \Sigma _ { z z } ^ { - 1 } \Sigma _ { z x } ) ^ { - 1 } )$

To get to this distribution do I take expectations conditional on $X, Z$ or $X$ and $Z$

or do I simply put the definition of $y$ into the definition of $\hat { \beta } _ { GI V }$ and solve.

i.e.

$\hat { \beta } _ { GI V } = ( X ^ { \prime } Z ( Z ^ { \prime } Z ) ^ { - 1 } Z ^ { \prime } X ) ^ { - 1 } X ^ { \prime } Z ( Z ^ { \prime } Z ) ^ { - 1 } Z^ { \prime }(X\beta + U)\hspace{70pt}(b)$

If I just plug in the definition of $y$ into $(a)$ I get $(b)$. How do I then justify $(d)$

$\hat { \beta } _ { GI V } = \beta + ( X ^ { \prime } Z ( Z ^ { \prime } Z ) ^ { - 1 } Z ^ { \prime } X ) ^ { - 1 } X ^ { \prime } Z ( Z ^ { \prime } Z ) ^ { - 1 } Z^ { \prime }U \hspace{70pt}(c)$

$Z^ { \prime }U=0\hspace{70pt}(d)$

Which results in $(e)$

$\hat { \beta } _ { GI V } = \beta \hspace{70pt}(e)$

Thank you for any help advice.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

For (c), it should be:

$$\mathrm{E}(\hat\beta_{GIV}) = \beta + ( X ^ { \prime } Z ( Z ^ { \prime } Z ) ^ { - 1 } Z ^ { \prime } X ) ^ { - 1 } X ^ { \prime } Z ( Z ^ { \prime } Z ) ^ { - 1 } Z^ { \prime }\mathrm{E}(U)$$.

For (d), it should be:
$$Z^ { \prime }\mathrm{E}(U) = 0$$

If you check the assumptions, you should find one of them is $\mathrm{E}(U) = 0$.

For (e), it should be:

$$\mathrm{E}(\hat\beta_{GIV}) = \beta$$